# Is it possible to use cookie-based single sign-on authentication scheme if sites do not share a common DNS parent domain?

Tags: authentication, cookies, single-sign-on

According to the "Single sign-on" page on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_sign-on):

> A simple version of single sign-on can be achieved over IP networks using cookies but only if the sites share a common DNS parent domain.

This means that if the user has authenticated on `login.foo.org`, then
the web-server on `login.foo.org` issues an authentication cookie for
`foo.org` domain and the user is able to authenticate on sites like
`billing.foo.org` or `wiki.foo.org` using that cookie. However, could
the `login.foo.org` make a request to `login.bar.org` after a
successful authentication and thus the user would get two
authentication cookies: first-party cookie for `foo.org` domain and
third-party cookie for `bar.org` domain?

Comment: This seems like it would work, if the user's browser allows third-party cookies.  Bear in mind that Firefox and Safari now block third-party cookies by default, and Chrome has plans to do so as well.  See https://www.theverge.com/2021/6/24/22547339/google-chrome-cookiepocalypse-delayed-2023.

Comment: IMO, from the server standpoint it's still possible to do that, but from the Browser side - it's old news. If you check out the date of that quote you can see it's from the good old 2007

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The quote you referenced is apparently from the year 2007 and the Browser developer opinion was completely different on Cookies back in the day. As the User @mti2935 pointed out before me 3rd-Party-Cookies are mostly blocked by browsers nowadays.

Nowadays, we are talking about abolishing cookies, thanks to the talks started by Google.

The OAuth 2.0 protocol highly likely offers what you need for SSO authorization nowadays.